# ArduPilot Quad Copter Drone Cannot Turn.

Tags: arduino

We are using an ardu-pilot Mega 2.5 to control our drone but only the left stick responds. We suspect it may be the controller but we are not sure. Is there any solutions to this problem we may have overlooked

Comment: How is this programming related if you suspect the hardware to be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked a lot with pixhawk. I believe if you can give little more information about what radio controller and protocol you are using, I can help. If your receiver supports PPM it should be fairly easy to control everything by one 3 wire connector. Else you need to have different connector for each channel to the APM Mega